# Notation for canonical morphism between quotients induced by a morphism

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathcal A$ be a category, $f : A \to B$ be a morphism, $(R_1,R_2 : R \to A)$ an equivalence relation on $A$, $(S_1,S_2 : S \to B)$ an equivalence relation on $B$ and $\operatorname{qt}_{A/R}$, $\operatorname{qt}_{B/S}$ coequalizers, respectively. Let $f$ be "relation preserving", i.e. there exists a (necessarily unique) morphism $\tilde f : R \to S$ making the obvious pair of diagrams commute (see below).

> What might be a good notation for the unique morphism $u$ (and perhaps name?) making also the right square in the following diagram commute:

[image: u is such that u o qt_{A/R} = qt_{B/S} o f]

In the set-theoretic case we would of course have $u([x]_R) = [f(x)]_S$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: I generally call it "the induced arrow/morphism", and denote it with $\bar{f}$ or $\hat{f}$, depending on the circumstances. I've read a few papers dealing about these things, I'll see if there are any trends.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I was hoping for something slightly more verbose involving $R,S$ and $f$.